# Dynamic row added to table: adding click event doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

Brain ache.

I have a timer that dynamically adds row to a table. I want an event to fire 
when the user clicks on one of the dynamically added rows.

I'm tagging each for with a class of "PortletTableUseButton" and using the .on("click") but it doesn't work.

```
    $('.PortletTableUseButton').on("click", function () {
        alert($(this));
    });
    setInterval(function () { addRow(); }, 2000);

    var counter = 2042;
    function addRow() {
        counter++;
        var myRow = "<tr class='PortletTableUseButton'><td>BLOCK-" + counter + "</td><td>Location A</td><td >Use</td></tr>";

        $("#Portlet #content tr:last").after(myRow);
    }
<div id="Portlet" style="position:absolute; top:500px;left:500px; height:200px;">
    <div id="content" style="height:80%;">
        <table id="PortletTable">
            <tr>
                <td>File Name</td>
                <td>Location</td>
                <td>Action</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't using event delegation correctly. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.PortletTableUseButton', function () { ... });
```

http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Alternatively, run your click function each time you add a row.

Comment: Thanks but no change. The event doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Sure it does. Are you seeing any syntax or other errors in the console? What does your HTML look like after a row has been added?

Comment: Thank you sir. you were right: you're code was correct. Thanks for the help: my brain's not aching so much now.